# Url rewrite with a dash in path does not properly redirect (404 error)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using firebase hosting, and I have set up the proper url rewrites in firebase.json as follows:

```
"rewrites": 
[{
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
}]
```

This seems to work fine, as all the routes go through the index.html as it should. However, when I have in the route an firebase object ID that begins with a "-" the it throws a 404. So for example `my-cool-app.firebaseapp.com/profiles/-JfZA03uAJI7rpqQg0sG` would return a 404. However, if I remove the dash in the id, the routes then seems to be rewrite properly.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, could you reach out to us at support@firebase.com with a specific example of this not working

Comment: Turned out to be a caching issue. Kind of weird. Doing a hard refresh solved the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Was a cache problem in your case?